# How can I print a warning message from within a custom module in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

I've created a custom module based on the description in the [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#creating-a-module).

The docs explain to fail the module with `module.fail_json()`. Instead of failing and printing an error message, I want to output just a warning message without failing. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible: How to print WARNINGs from playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036628/6771046)

Comment: @U880D even though the question there doesn't explicitly ask for a warning out of a custom module, the linked answer does explain how to do that, so yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `warn()` method to do that. For example

```py
module.warn(f"test warning printing the module argument {module.params['name']}")
```

which prints out:

```bash
[WARNING]: test warning printing the module argument myName
```

For general printout the [Display class](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/utils/display.py#L255) can be used.